# std::experimental::optional inside constexpr function

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, option-type, constexpr

I would like to use the optional idiom inside my constexpr function to easily clarify if the variable is set or not.

What I have tried with std::experimental::optional:

```
constexpr bool call()
{
  std::experimental::optional<bool> r; 
  r = true; // Error
  // Similar error with:
  // r = std::experimental::optional<bool>(true);

  if (!r)
  {
    return false;
  }
  return *r;
}
```

I get the error: *call to non-constexpr function* - so the assignment is not possible, because this operation cannot be constexpr ([Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:'%23include+%3Cexperimental/optional%3E%0A%0Aconstexpr+bool+call()%0A%7B%0A++std::experimental::optional%3Cbool%3E+r%3B+%0A++r+%3D+true%3B%0A++%0A++if+(!!r)%0A++%7B%0A++++return+false%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+*r%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconstexpr+bool+f+%3D+call()%3B')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)).

But if I implement my own (very ugly, [just for example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',sourcez:FAFwpgtgDgNghuAPCAnlMA7OEwAIAqAfMAM4gBOArgMYi4D2UIAlvVjMAN7C64BG9ejFwQA%2BgGUwIANw8CI0QBEEcWbznU2ZMAA8o5Bk1bsAFAEpcALjm8xkkCYBmcGCTBmANAuUg4nAL5y3LyB6ryaGNp6BowsbC4m%2BLhQSioW1ry2ElImFJTuXmI%2BcCYpxWZBcqG4crqwzNTMdBFR%2BoZg5Aj0BgJC5pWZuORSlOQYCvZquNUaWuDR8owdXQYAVP28wZnDIKPjRSpTgf6ywC3zbb3C1C4wAEz9W7HGLohXhENTBgC8uHlgUzkzEcuBMAEJyBVNjYhiMxrhnK4AVU5Ds9rhVuRZIFgGc5nUeoJhI47rhfjcYPdzNIgA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)) optional class, it works, because I don´t implement the assignment operator/constructor explicit.

```
template<typename T>
struct optional
{
  bool m_Set;
  T m_Data;

  constexpr optional() :
    m_Set(false), m_Data{}
  {
  }

  constexpr optional(T p_Data) :
    m_Set(true), m_Data(p_Data)
  {
  }

  explicit constexpr operator bool()
  {
    return m_Set;
  }

  constexpr T operator *()
  {
    return m_Data;
  }
};
```

How could I use std::..::optional in the same context with assignment inside constexpr functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as explained in [n3527](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#rationale.constexpr):

> #### Making `optional` a literal type
>
> We propose that `optional<T>` be a literal type for trivially
>   destructible T's.
>
> ```
> constexpr optional<int> oi{5};
> static_assert(oi, "");            // ok
> static_assert(oi != nullopt, ""); // ok
> static_assert(oi == oi, "");      // ok
> int array[*oi];                   // ok: array of size 5
> ```
>
> Making `optional<T>` a literal-type in general is impossible: the
>   destructor cannot be trivial because it has to execute an operation
>   that can be conceptually described as:
>
> ```
> ~optional() {
>   if (is_engaged()) destroy_contained_value();
> }
> ```
>
> It is still possible to make the destructor trivial for `T`'s which
>   provide a trivial destructor themselves, and we know an efficient
>   implementation of such `optional<T>` with compile-time interface —
>   except for copy constructor and move constructor — is possible.
>   Therefore we propose that for trivially destructible `T`'s all
>   `optional<T>`'s constructors, except for move and copy constructors,
>   as well as observer functions are constexpr. The sketch of reference
>   implementation is provided in this proposal.

In other words, it's not possible to assign a value to `r` even if you mark it as constexpr. You must initialize it in the same line.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you can't. The problem with your simple implementation is that it requires `T` be default-constructible - if this is not the case, this won't work.

To get around this, most implementation use either a `union` or some (suitably aligned) storage that can hold a `T`. If you are passed a `T` in the constructor, then all well and good, you can initialize this directly (hence it will be `constexpr`). However, the tradeoff here is that when calling `operator=`, copying the value across may require a placement-new call, which cannot be `constexpr`.

For example, from LLVM:

```
template <class _Up,
      class = typename enable_if
              <
                  is_same<typename remove_reference<_Up>::type, value_type>::value &&
                  is_constructible<value_type, _Up>::value &&
                  is_assignable<value_type&, _Up>::value
              >::type
          >
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
optional&
operator=(_Up&& __v)
{
    if (this->__engaged_)
        this->__val_ = _VSTD::forward<_Up>(__v);
    else
    {
        // Problem line is below - not engaged -> need to call 
        // placement new with the value passed in.
        ::new(_VSTD::addressof(this->__val_)) value_type(_VSTD::forward<_Up>(__v));
        this->__engaged_ = true;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

As for why placement new is not `constexpr`, see [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/_s7vi9pOhfY).

Answer (score 1):

> How could I use std::..::optional in the same context with assignment
>   inside constexpr functions?

[`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) is meant to hold a value that may or may not be present. The problem with [`std::optional`'s assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/operator%3D) is that it must destroy the old state (call the destructor of the contained object) if any. And you cannot have a `constexpr` destructor.

Of cause, Trivial and integral types shouldn't have a problem, but I presume the generalization was to keep things sane. However, Assignment could have been made `constexpr` for trivial types. Hopefully, it will be corrected. Before then, you can role out yours. :-)

Even `std::optional`'s constructor that you think is `constexpr`, is actually selectively `constexpr` (depending on whether the selected object constructor is). *Its proposal can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `constexpr` support in `std::optional` is somewhat rudimentary; the `constexpr`-enabled member functions are just the (empty and engaged) constructors, the destructor and some observers, so you cannot alter the engaged state of an optional.

This is because there would be no way to implement assignment for non-trivially copyable types without using placement new and in-place destruction of the contained object, which is illegal within `constexpr` context.  The same currently holds for copy and move constructors, although that may change with guaranteed copy elision, but in any case the standard marks those special member functions as non-`constexpr`, so you cannot use them in `constexpr` context.

The fix would be to make the assignment operator conditionally `constexpr` dependent on whether the contained type is trivial (`std::is_trivial_v<T>`).

There is some discussion of this issue [at the reference implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/issues/35#issuecomment-194326183); although it's probably too late to get `constexpr` assignment for trivial optionals into the next version of the Standard, there's nothing preventing you writing your own (e.g. by copying and fixing the reference implementation).